# Bilinear Transformation $\frac{i z+2}{4z+i }$

Tags: complex-analysis

The Bilinear Transformation

> $$f(z)=\frac{i z+2}{4z+i }$$ maps real and imaginary axis on a circle of radius?

**solution i tried**- When axis is real so $y$ in $z$ is zero so we have $z=x$ so we get

> $$u+iv=\frac{4x^2i+9x-2i}{16x^2+1}$$

and when i solve for imaginary axis i got

> $$u+iv=\frac{yi+2i}{4y+1}$$

but how to think further not getting a clue

please help

Thankyou

Comment: where ?,i did't get it ,can you please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly discovered that points on the real axis of the form $(x,0)$ are mapped to $\left(\frac {9x}{16x^2+1},\frac{4x^2-2}{16x^2+1}\right)$

We are told that these points lie on a circle and we want to find its radius.
We are not asked to show that these points lie on a circle, so let's just believe that.

Consider $x=0$. Then $u=0$, $v=-2$.
Consider $x\rightarrow\infty$. Then $u\rightarrow0$, $v\rightarrow \frac14$.

The top of the circle is $\left(0,\frac14\right)$ and the bottom of the circle is $\left(0,-2\right)$.

That should be enough to say that the radius is $\frac{2--\frac14}2=\frac98$, but in case you're not convinced, we can also consider the leftmost and rightmost points of the circle.

From $u=\frac{9x}{16x^2+1}$ we can find $\frac {du}{dx}=\frac{9-144x^2}{\left(16x^2+1\right)^2}$

Solving $\frac {du}{dx}=0$ gives $x=\pm \frac14$

These correspond to $\left(-\frac98,-\frac78\right)$ and $\left(\frac98,-\frac78\right)$, which confirm that the radius is $\frac98$.

You have also discovered that points on the imaginary axis of the form $(0,y)$ are mapped to $\left(0,\frac{y-2}{4y+1}\right)$. These points are **not on a circle**.

Comment: +1, for your comment ,but how can we say $(0,1/4)$ and $(0,-2)$ is on opposite ends?

Comment: is this because of stereographic projection?

Comment: Draw the graph of $v=\frac{4x^2-2}{16x^2+1}$. You will see that it has a maximum value at $x=0$ and minimum value as $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$. These correspond to the maximum and minimum of the circle.

Comment: Thank you @tomi for your precious time ,Now i fully understand this.